# two select menus with the same parameters in a form rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a nested form where there are two possible select menus for the same value. At the moment only one of the location_ids is present in the params if both select menus are present.
So even if I select a value in `@common_locations_array` and leave `@possible_locations` blank, the parameters do not contain the relevant id. However if I select something from `@possible_locations` and leave `@common_locations_array` blank the value is in the params. I guess its to do with the ordering.

```
 =f.simple_fields_for @job.job_locations.build do |p|
    =p.input :location_id, collection: @common_locations_array, label: 'Popular Locations'
    =p.input :location_id, collection: @possible_locations, label: 'Clients Locations'
```

So what would be a way around this? Would I specify my own custom parameter for each one of select menus? if so how would you do that?

Or should I merge the two arrays with some kind of divider in the select menu two seperate the two categories? How would I do that?

I'm not sure.

Thanks

Comment: why do you have same database field for both the selects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the `name` attribute of the `input` tag that is getting generated. As you have specified the same name to both your input fields, the `name` that might be getting generated would be same, i.e., `job_locations[location_id]`.

Now, as HTML is executed top-to-bottom, the ones written below will eventually get converted to your prams hash. So, your `params[:job_locations][:location_id]` will always have the value that is selected in the second drop-down. To avoid this, you can give different names to the two drop-downs.

like

```
=p.input :popular_location_id, collection: @common_locations_array, label: 'Popular Locations'
=p.input :client_location_id, collection: @possible_locations, label: 'Clients Locations'
```

Now, both the params can be accessed via: `params[:job_location][:popular_location_id]` and `params[:job_location][:client_location_id]`